# atk4 dialogURL close button

Tags: php, user-interface, frameworks, atk4

I'm using atk dialogURL with button false, i've some fields and added my buttons:

```
$f2->addSubmit();
$f2->addButton('Close')->js('click',$f2->js()->univ()->closeDialog());
if($f->isSubmitted()){
        $f->update();
}
```

after push "Save" button my dialog don't close (I don't want it) then I click my close button dialog, but appear :

"'Changes on the form will be lost. Continue?'"

why? my data is correct saved in database. Seem that .form_changed is not updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside isSubmitted, you need to explicitly close the dialog:

```
if($f->isSubmitted()){
    $f->update();
    $f->js()->univ()->closeDialog()->execute();
}
```

By default before dialog is destroyed it checks if it's been changed. It's implemented by adding a class (form_changed) to the form tag. You have few other options. For example, you can remove the form altogether:

```
if($f->isSubmitted()){
    $f->update();
    $f->js()->remove()->execute()
}
```

Or:

```
$this->addButton('Close')->js('click',
    $form->js()->find('form')->removeClass('form_changed')
)->univ()->closeDialog();
```